# How to validate group of checkboxes in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, unobtrusive-validation

I have following property in my view model

```
public IList<KeyWordViewModel> KeyWords { get; set; }
```

In my .cshtml file I am rendering checkboxes like this:

```
<div>
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.KeyWords.Count; i++)
{
    <div>
    @*@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.KeyWords[i].KeyWord)*@
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.KeyWords[i].Checked)
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.KeyWords[i].Checked, Model.KeyWords[i].KeyWord)
    </div>
}
</div>
```

I need some way to validate this group of check boxes on client side using jquery jquery.validate.unobtrusive.

Can someone please suggest. I created following custom attribute, but client side validation never occurs.

```
public class CheckListRequiredAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    int _min;
    int _max;
    string _propertyName;
    public CheckListRequiredAttribute(int min = 1, int max = int.MaxValue, string propertyName = "Checked")
    {

        this._min = min;
        this._max = max;
        this._propertyName = propertyName;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        IList list;
        if (value == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        if (value.GetType().Name == typeof(List<>).Name || value.GetType().Name == typeof(IList<>).Name)
        {
            list = (IList)value;
        }
        else
        {
            list = new object[] { value };
        }
        if (list.Count < 0)
            return null;

        var checkedItems = (from object item in list let propertyInfo = item.GetType().GetProperties() from info in propertyInfo where String.Equals(info.Name, _propertyName) && (bool)info.GetValue(item, null) == true select item).ToList();
        if (checkedItems.Count >= _min && checkedItems.Count <= _max)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return new ValidationResult(FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        yield return new ModelClientValidationRule
        {
            ErrorMessage = FormatErrorMessage(metadata.GetDisplayName()),
            ValidationType = "checklistrequired"
        };
    }
}
```

I have following validator registration code

```
$(function () {

    jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add('checklistrequired', {}, function (options) {
        options.rules['checklistrequired'] = {};
        if (options.message) {
            options.messages['checklistrequired'] = options.message;
        }
    });

    jQuery.validator.addMethod('checklistrequired', function (value, element, params) {
        alert("Testing cb validation");     
    return false;   
    }, 'Please check at least one box.');

} (jQuery));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have it, just missing the actual client-side portion. Remember that what you write server-side isn't auto-translated to client-side javascript. You can use AJAX checking, but that (IMHO) puts unnecessary queries in the mix (especially for such a simple check)).

To add the client side validator you can place something like the following on the page:

```
$.validator.addMethod('checklistrequired', function(value, element){
  // check the values selected and return an outcome
});
```

Then, this will wire up with your `ModelClientValidationRule.ValidationType` which was specified as `checklistrequired`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I already have that code in place and still not working. Server side validation work without any issues.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see it in the answer and didn't know you had it. with that said, do you get any JS errors on page load? Could be a chicken-or-the-egg: what order do you include the validation libraries?

Comment: I have /Common/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js first (all other jquery related files comes before this ) and then the script block after that. In fact the script block is the last thing on the page.

Comment: i believe you want `jquery.validate.js` first, then your user-defined validation, then `jquery.*unobtrusive*.js` thereafter. This way the validation object exists, you add your customized logic, then unobtrusive goes and wires everything up (with your custom validator now available).

Comment: I just did that and I get "Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'validator.unobtrusive.adapters' is null or not an object"

Comment: @user: i stand corrected, the custom validator does come after the jquery and unobtrusive. though i did find a couple interesting reads: http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-validation.html as well as http://www.headspring.com/mvc-custom-unobtrusive-validator-attribute-date-range-validation/ (I've never done it with the adapters)

Comment: Looks like it doesn't fires GetClientValidationRules method if CheckListRequired attribute is decorated on a property that is of IList, if the property is say bool etc.. meaning non collection. It works, so looks like MVC4 client side validation does not work for client side works only on server side.

Comment: @user357086 I know that it was long time ago but I have the same problem. Do you have an idea how to solve this and how to fire `GetClientValidationRules`?